# Error: How to toggle between hiding and showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
body {
    margin: 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: lightseagreen;
}
a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
}
/* whole bar*/
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:  space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding:  9px 12px;
}
/* Menu*/
.navbar_menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-family: initial;
}

.navbar_menu li {
    padding: 8px 30px;  
    display: inline;
}

.navbar_icons {

    letter-spacing:30px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 200px;
    color: lightgray;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left:0;

}
/* Icons */
.navbar__icons li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    display: none;
  }
/* Toggle button */
.navbar_toogleBtn{
    position: absolute;
    /*화면이 작아졌을때만 나타남*/
    display: none;
    right: 32px;
    font-size: 24px;
}

/*For small screen */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
      /* Nav container */
    .navbar{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 8px 24px;
    }
 
      /* Menu */
    .navbar_menu{
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        justify-content: center;

    }
   .navbar_menu li{
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
       display: block;    
   }

   .navbar__menu a {
    /* Fill in an entire line so that user can click on any space */
    display: block;
    
  }

   /* Icons */
    .navbar_icons {
        justify-content: center;
        display: none;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        
    }
      /* Toggle button */
    .navbar_toogleBtn{
        display: block;
    }
    /* When toggle button is clicked - active state */
    .navbar_menu.active,
    .navbar_icons.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bar.css" />
    <title>first page</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/265fcd9b69.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar">

        <div class="navbar_logo">
            <img src="logo.png" width="300" height="200">

        </div>
      <!-- Menu -->
        <ul class="navbar_menu">
            <!-- info.html, partner.html, free.html를 임의로 적어둠 -->
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Info.html">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="Partner.html">Partner</a></li>
            <li><a href="Free.html">Freelencer</a></li>
            <li><a href="Comunity.html">Comunity</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Icons -->
        <ul class="navbar_icons">
            <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></li>
            <li><a href="register.html"><i class="far fa-registered"></i></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Toggle button -->
        <a href="#" class="navbar_toogleBtn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"> </i>
        </a>

    </nav>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="bar.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.navbar__toggleBtn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
const icons = document.querySelector('.navbar__icons');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
  icons.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Im learning html/css/js from a  Youtube video tutorial. Im learning how to write js code but i can't help to solve a problem. I hope you give me the solution guys.

The problem is about add.EventListener. i saw the code in chrome, in console it shows:

> "bar.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

I would like to use toggle hide and show with JS.

Comment: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" Following error is caused when you try to access the element that is not present. In case of your check element that has been assigned to add variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error ( *"bar.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"* ) because you are specifying invalid element classes in js.

Use this:

```
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.navbar_toogleBtn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.navbar_menu');
const icons = document.querySelector('.navbar_icons');
```

Since your elements in html are:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar_toogleBtn">
...
<ul class="navbar_menu">
...
<ul class="navbar_icons">
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to be specific as to what your issue is. Null is the absence of a value or object. When we call on a selector that does not exist, we can trigger the same error of null. Check if you are targeting an id that exists or that you are targeting the correct element using it's class.

Cross-reference your code to the following example to see if you may have missed something. This is the most basic of examples.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if( box.classList.contains('active') ){
    box.classList.remove('active'); 
  } else {
    box.classList.add('active') ;
  }
});
```

```css
#button {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#box {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#box.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="box">I am a box. Watch me.</div>
```